# Making a search addresses (like google map) in python-flask application

Tags: python, flask

I want to add an address field in WTF form in my python-flask application. The field should  provide autocomplete suggestions of the street names as the user starts typing in. I don't want to show a map, just the list of street addresses for the user to choose from. Can anybody suggest how can I achieve this? Any demo or link to a tutorial would help.

Thanks!

Comment: i'm not a expert or anything but i know there exists a type database which can do what your asking

Answer (score 1):

This is called Live Search and can be implemented in Flask using jQuery to listen to changes in the search field on the client side and then send a Ajax (An Ajax requests makes sure the page doesn't has to be reloaded) request to the server containing the query.

The server now performs a query on the database, I would recommend MongoDB as it's easy to setup and has inbuilt autocomplete and fuzzy search.(https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/autocomplete/)

The database response can now be sent as the response to the Ajax query and now the search box can be filled with live-time suggestions.

The client side Ajax -

```
$("#search-input").on("input", function() {
    var query = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/livesearch",
        data: { query: query },
        success: function(data) {
            // Update the search suggestions in the page
        }
    });
});
```

Flask side code -

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
client = MongoClient()
database = client.your_database

@app.route('/livesearch', methods=["GET"])
def autocomplete():
    query = request.args.get("query")
    suggestions = database .your_collection.find({"$text": {"$search": query}})
    return jsonify([sug['address'] for sug in suggestions])
```

Make sure to add CSRF protection as this route will be public.